# Trying to store/save scores in MySQL database table

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am building a quiz program, using PHP, and MySQL.

I built the quiz program such that: the same file (**Quiz.php**) is called over and over again, but each time is selects a new question from the database.

The MySQL database contains a field "my_score". Any time the player answers a question correctly, a score of "1" is added to his current score. The player clicks "**Next**", and the SAME file is re-processed (Quiz.php)

Whenever he answers wrongly, nothing happens. The quiz simply exits.

I know that this issue is trivial, but I can't seem to get the logic right. I've tried using $_SESSION, but of course, this didn't work, as the variables are stored only when the user is logged on. If he logs off, and then comes back again to play, the "**score**" is reset to 1.

What I want is for the score to be updated in the database with each correct answer.

```
  if ($selected_radio == $correct) {   // if player selects correct answer..

  $_SESSION['quiz_score'] += 1;

  $my_score = $_SESSION['quiz_score'];

  $update_score = "Update my_table

  set my_score = $my_score where login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";

  $result_update_score = mysqli_query($conn,$update_score);
```

Then, I removed the $_SESSION variable, and simply used $my_score :

```
  if ($selected_radio == $correct) {     

  $my_score += 1;

  $update_score = "Update my_table

  set my_score = $my_score where login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";
```

It gave the same result.

Comment: Get "my_score" from "my_table" via a select statement first.  If "my_score" comes back as null just set to 0 initially

Comment: Add a field in your table where you save the total score of every user and after the login make a query to get that total and asign it to the variable that you want, that way you will get the total score everytime for every user

Comment: @Hali Hydra:   Your suggestion worked best!   

Thanks )

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using $update_score = "Update my_table

set my_score += $my_score where login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";

so the points would just add up again to your stored score on the database?